# Rolling window correlation calculations for different time step in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a DataFrame with returns for different securities across a few year. I would like to calculate correlations in  100 day windows for the last day of every month.

```
rolcor = pd.rolling_corr(df2,window=100,pairwise = True)

Date            Sec1          Sec2          Sec3          Sec4    ....
...
2006-01-24      0.000595     -0.009683     -0.004044      0.020969   ....
2006-01-25      0.013976      0.024152     -0.001015      0.019122   ....
2006-01-26      0.011730      0.008323      0.026423     -0.006254   ....
2006-01-27      0.020290      0.000000      0.014851      0.004196   ....
2006-01-30      0.046875      0.018937      0.000000      0.007660   ....
2006-01-31     -0.049118     -0.014852     -0.006829     -0.005529   ....
....
```

`pd.rolling_corr` does the calculations, but  they're done for all data points in the original DataFrame while I need only for the last day of each month. Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you only want to consider the price at the last day of the month

```
periods = n
index = pd.date_range('2006-01-31', periods=n, freq='M')
print index

DatetimeIndex(['2006-01-31', '2006-02-28', ... , '2006-10-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

then use this to slice out the month end values.

```
df2.loc[index]
```

Something tells me that is not what you want though?

Comment: It's not. Basically I'd like to do what the `pd.rolling_corr(df2,window=100,pairwise = True)` does, but to have the correlation matrices not for all the dates in the df2, just for example for the end of the month dates, or for every 20th date in df2.
I.e. so that the returned DataFrame would have not the `2006-01-24, 2006-01-25, 2006-01-26, 2006-01-27, 2006-01-28,  ...` dates but 2006-01-31, 2006-02-28, 2006-03-31, 2006-04-30, 2006-05-31,...`. I could extract it from the  current `pd.rolling_corr(df2,window=100,pairwise = True)` result, but I want to reduce the computation time.